# Pass integer to line of code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pass an integer "i" to a line in code:

```
Dim i As Integer

i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Value
If Ans = vbYes Then Sheets("Sheet1").Image(i).Picture = LoadPicture(Pict)
```

I have many different image controls and depending on the value in range A8 I want to pass that # as "i" to line of code above.

Comment: What language is this for? Is this for excel?

Comment: Try `i = CInt(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Value2)` By the way what value,text etc does `A8` contains ? You can also check if Range("A8") really has any numeric value using `IsNumeric` function. I don't think the real problem is passing the integer value.

Comment: The part of the question that I need to know about is what are the names of the controls that contain the pictures? I think that you might be trying to access an array of controls that does not exist.

Comment: @Santosh
A8 does contain a numeric value. The names of the ActiveX Image controls are Image1...Image25

Answer (score 0):

The cint() function will take the value and cast(convert) it to the Integer variable type before storing it into the i variable. You can also use the array of image control references to modify them directly through the index value i.

```
i = CInt(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Value)
If Ans = vbYes Then imagelist(i).Picture = LoadPicture(Pict)
```

In the excel spreadsheet VBA editor you need to do the following.

Insert a new Module and add this line to it

```
Global imagelist(1 To 25) As Variant
```

Now under the Workbook object

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set imagelist(1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Image1
Set imagelist(2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Image2
...
Set imagelist(24) = Sheets("Sheet1").Image24
Set imagelist(25) = Sheets("Sheet1").Image25
End Sub
```

This will allow you to access the image controls using the imagelist(i) in your code, and the global variable will allow any code in the entire spreadsheet to be able to access those pictures.

Comment: If the cell does not contain a numeric value, the Cint() will return 0

Comment: it did not work. how do i put it in the line of code as Image(i) ?

Comment: Need to know what type of object you are storing your pictures in. That would be helpful.

Comment: Image ActiveX control on worksheet. If I put a number like .Image1 it works fine but i need to references many control named Image1....Image25 and a combo box is setting the value in the "A8" range

Comment: There are ways to access controls using an indirect reference, but this is a ways to give you the most direct solution to your question.

Comment: Still not working. I'm testing via a user form command button click event that opens a browser and allows user to select a picture file and to then insert it onto the ActiveX image control. If I put any number like .Image13 it works as expected but still not passing the A8 value into the code

Comment: @FTSC This is a compund solution. You need to add a module so that you can create the global array of variants; add the Workbook_Open code to the workbook object specifically; then you need to update your code in the other procedures. Before you can make it work, you need to close and open the file to allow the global to be populated; it goes without saying that you need to be using a macro enabled excel file...

Comment: Followed your instructions and all is a you requested but still not working.thanks for your efforts

Comment: Some of these problems have so many "moving parts" that we just can't anticipate everything you are dealing with. Thanks for taking time to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't represent a codename variable like this, so the only way you can do it us by accessing the collection of image objects, and finding the item you want using it's name as the index.

For example:

```
'// Sheet1 object has a tab name of "My Sheet 1"

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Foo"   '// This will work.
Sheet(i).Range("A1").Value = "Foo" '// This will not work.
```

In the above example, the compiler is looking for a collection called `Sheet` and trying to access the item at index 1 (because `i` = 1). That collection doesn't exist and so the code errors.

---

In these scenarios, you have to look for the global collecion of objects and access *that* instead. Referring back to the above example you would use:

```
Sheets("My Sheet " & i).Range("A1").Value = "Foo"
```

---

So in your example, you need to identify which collection the images belong to (e.g. the `Shapes` collection) and then use something like:

```
If Ans = vbYes Then Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Image" & i).Picture = LoadPicture(Pict)
```

*(I've used the shapes collection here as an example, it might not be the right one for you but the point is based around getting an item from the collection so you should be able to adapt it)*

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    i = .Range("A8").Value
    .Shapes.Item("ImageList" & i).Picture = LoadPicture(Pict)
End With
```

or you could use

```
    .oleobjects.item("ImageList"& i).Picture = LoadPicture(Pict)
```